# Angular 6, RxJS return undefined object

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

my map/filter function aren't returning an object that I am recieving from my in-memory-service.

```
this.myService.getEventMedia().subscribe(
  (response) => {
    return response.map((res) => {
      this.returnObj = res.dataObj.filter((data) => {
       if(data.id === id) {
         console.log('event is ', data)
         return data;
       }

      })
    })
  }
);
```

after this response and/or ngAfterViewInit() returnObj is console logging undefinded. My data from the filter function has value in it and i can console log data.id

my model looks like below

```
export interface Model {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  data: Data[];
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't return something from a `subscribe` block. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to assign the matching data to returnObj, i'm still new to rxjs so still learning

Comment: @Generaldeep can you show the json for `response`?

Comment: @CozyAzure, the response is an object with 2 arrays that contains multiple objects. I can't share the json response due to privacy issues.

Comment: `filter` inside `map` is not a good idea, though

Comment: @CastroRoy, suggestion on how to extract the inner object that matches the Id from url param? instead of filter inside map?

Comment: @Generaldeep just use `filter` if you want to return more than one object, or use `find` if you are looking for just one object. `map` is used for transforming every item in the array, but usually when we expect an array that will have the same amount of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe change your service subscription to this?

```
this.myService.getEventMedia().subscribe(
  (response) => {
    this.returnObject = response.map((res) => {
      return res.dataObj.filter((data) => {
       if(data.id === id) {
         console.log('event is ', data)
         return data;
       }
      })
    })
  }
);
```

This way your return object is getting set to the map. Right now returning your map isn't doing anything for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should not return values from the callback methods passed to `subscribe`, as they are all void in the method signature.

If what you want to do is transform the response of your service in some manner, and then assign the transformed value to the returnObj class member, then you should do something like the following:

```
this.myService.getEventMedia()
  .pipe(
      map(response => this.transformResponse(response))
   )
  .subscribe(mappedResponse => this.returnObj = mappedResponse);

private transformResponse(response:Object): Object {
   // your transformation logic goes here
}
```